# Run a Visual Studio event on build failure?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Is it possible to run a file or command/event when compiling a `c++` project using the Visual Studio IDE (not compiling trough cmd / MSBuild.exe) and the build fails?

Or maybe a way to save the `Output` window verbose to a log file?

I tried looking into the API calls made by the `Output` window but I couldn't find any way to read this message:

`========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: Hi, have you got any updates?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try to select Tools in the menu bar, then select Options in the drop-down box, and set `the output and log file verbosity` to detailed as shown below.

[image]

Finally, open the .log file in the project folder, which contains detailed information about the project.

[image]